# Force semantic error (failed predicate) in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Basically, I've extended the BaseErrorListener, and I need to know when the error is semantic and when it's syntactic. So I want the following to give me a failed predicate exception, but I'm getting a `NoViableAltException` instead (I know the counting is working, because I can print out the value of `things`, and it's correct). Is there a way I can re-work it to do what I want? In my example below, I want there to be a failed predicate exception if we don't end up with 6 `things`.

```
grammar Test;

@parser::members {
    int things = 0;
}
.
.
.
samplerule : THING { things++; } ;
.
.
.
// Want this to be a failed predicate instead of NoViableAltException
anotherrule : ENDTOKEN { things == 6 }? ;
.
.
.
```

---

I'm already properly getting failed predicate exceptions with the following (for a different scenario):

```
somerule : { Integer.valueOf(getCurrentToken().getText()) < 256 }? NUMBER ;
.
.
.
NUMBER : [0-9]+ ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to [280Z28's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/138304/280z28) answer and the apparent fact that predicates should not be used for what I was trying to do, I went a different route.

*If you know what you're looking for*, ANTLR4's documentation is actually pretty useful--visit [Parser.getCurrentToken()](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/Parser.html#getCurrentToken())'s documentation and poke around further to see what more you can do with my implementation below.

My driver ended up looking something like the following:

```
// NameOfMyGrammar.java
public class NameOfMyGrammar {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String inputFile = args[0];

        try {
            ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRFileStream(inputFile);

            NameOfMyGrammarLexer lexer = new NameOfMyGrammarLexer(input);

            CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);

            MyCustomParser parser = new MyCustomParser(tokens);

            try {
                // begin parsing at "start" rule
                ParseTree tree = parser.start();
                // can print out parse tree if you want..
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                // Handle errors if you want..
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e);
        }   
    }

    // extend ANTLR-generated parser
    private static class MyCustomParser extends NameOfMyGrammarParser {

        // Constructor (my understanding is that you DO need this)
        public MyCustomParser(TokenStream input) {
            super(input);
        }

        @Override
        public Token getCurrentToken() {
            // Do your semantic checking as you encounter tokens here..
            // Depending on how you want to handle your errors, you can
            // throw exceptions, print out errors, etc.

            // Make sure you end by returning the current token
            return _input.LT(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In ANTLR 4, predicates should *only* be used in cases where your input leads to two different possible parse trees (ambiguous grammar) and the default handling is producing the wrong parse tree. You should create a listener or visitor implementation containing your logic for semantic validation of the source.